# In Struts2 how to do permanent redirects (status code 301) without having the parameter appearing in the URL

Tags: java, redirect, struts2, http-status-code-301

I have a Struts2 (version 2.2.3) web application. I am trying to redirect old links to new pages. I know I can do this via

```
    <action name="old-action" class="MVRActionClass">
        <result type="redirectAction">
            <param name="actionName">new-action</param>
            <param name="namespace">/new-action-namespace</param>
            <param name="statusCode">301</param>
        </result>
    </action>
```

But this adds a parameter `statusCode=301` in the final redirected url. I do not want this to happen. So I implemented some other approaches but it did not work out.

E.g. I tried to set the `status` in the response object before returning from the action like so -

```
@Override
public String execute() {
    ...     
    ((HttpServletResponse) response).setStatus(301);
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

This did not work. I was still getting 302 status for the link. Then I created an Interceptor and added a PreResultListener to it like so -

```
public class MyInterceptor extends AbstractInterceptor {

@Override
public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {

  invocation.addPreResultListener(new PreResultListener() { 
    @Override
    public void beforeResult(ActionInvocation invocation, String resultCode) {

      try {
    ActionContext actionContext = invocation.getInvocationContext();

    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse).actionContext.get(StrutsStatics.HTTP_RESPONSE);

     response.setStatus(301);
     actionContext.put(StrutsStatics.HTTP_RESPONSE, response);


      } catch(Exception e) {
        invocation.setResultCode("error");
      }
    }
  });

  // Invocation Continue
      return invocation.invoke();
    }
  }
}
```

Even this did not work. I was still getting 302 status for the link.

I also looked in to `redirect type=httpheader`. But I dont think it is what I want exactly. Since I need to send 301 along with content of the redirectedTo page i.e. new link.

There is some mention of subclassing `org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletActionRedirectResult` and then adding `statusCode` to the prohibited list. But I do not know how to inject this custom `RedirectResult` in the workflow.

Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE**
[I have posted the answer below.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14693816/131315)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like `statusCode` isn't removed from the parameter list during result processing.

To use your *own* result type, just define it as any other result type and use it instead of `redirectAction`. This is discussed in the [Result Configuration docs](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/result-configuration.html). You should just be able to override `getProhibitedResultParams()` and add `statusCode` to the list.

IMO statusCode should be on that list. There's a [JIRA ticket for this already](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-3389).

Comment: Thanks for responding. Actually already there is an open ticket for this. see here https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-3389

Comment: The link given on "Result configuration docs" looks like broken. This information now is available at here - https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/result-types.html

Answer (score 0):

If someone has  the same issue as me, this is how I resolved it based on [Dave's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14666512/131315).

First declare the result type in your package in which you will be calling on this result type.

```
    <result-types>
       <result-type name="premanentRedirectAction" 
                    class="management.dispatcher.ServletActionPermanentRedirectResult" />
    </result-types>
```

And then just simply define the result type like so -

```
package management.dispatcher;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletActionRedirectResult;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

public class ServletActionPermanentRedirectResult extends ServletActionRedirectResult {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 4921150146065435746L;

@Override
protected List<String> getProhibitedResultParams() {
    List<String> prohibitedResultParams = Lists.newArrayList(super.getProhibitedResultParams());
    prohibitedResultParams.add("statusCode");

    return prohibitedResultParams;
   }
   }
```

And then wherever you want to redirect with 301 if an old action have the following mapping -

```
    <action name="media-coverage">
        <result type="premanentRedirectAction">
            <param name="actionName">press</param>
            <param name="namespace">/</param>
            <param name="statusCode">301</param>
        </result>
    </action>
```